How can I make a simple automation with lua?
I've been learning Lua for a few months, but I want to do interesting things, and I was wondering how I could create a script for a simple automation, like: opening Google, typing 'hello world' in the search bar, and hitting enter. I haven't found any libraries and couldn't figure it out at all, it's quite frustrating. Could any kind soul give me an idea of how to do this?
I just want to do a simple automation in Lua. I tried some libraries recommended by AI, one of them was called luacom, and I didn't have success with any of them.

Wrong tool, for stuff like this you might want to take a look at AutoHotkey and co

Actually, I found a library called Lua Selenium that worked for me, anyways, thanks!
